# For multiple insertion what is important? Time or Memory?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, orm

Suppose There are two models (blogs and posts).
Relation: one blog has many posts

Now I want to create 50 posts for a blog. There are two ways :

1. I can create one by one. 50 queries will be run for 50 posts.
2. I can create 50 objects(posts) first. Then I can run one query for saving all the post and no callbacks will be triggered here.

Is there any disadvantages with the second one in terms of time and memory?
In which way you should go?

Comment: It's easy enough to test and compare -- but a single query is usually faster.

Comment: Single query is faster but I think for that ram has to hold a large block of array? Will it create any effect on memory?

Comment: 50 model instances usually don't take up a huge amount of memory. 50 database queries  will take time.

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors so it will depend on what you have running. A database can be configured to be performant with many small writes or large writes less frequently.

Your server may or may not be able to handle the second case depending on the memory, the complexity of the model, and the number of requests coming in at once. The main tradeoff with batching is that one bad object can cause the whole call to be unsuccessful. It's also not FIFO which less technical users might expect to be the case.

In general, there is likely not much of a gap between the two methods when the amount of actions is 50. Typically such a difference is observed at larger orders of magnitude or under heavy loads.